# How to solve this IAP content package uploading error in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to upload an Apple-hosted non-consumable IAP package via Xcode. It validates just fine. But when I attempt to submit it, I get these errors:

> - Apple's web service operation was not successful
> - Unable to authenticate the package: 693344215.itmsp
> - ERROR ITMS-4029: "Caught exception while parsing package "YourApp"" at Bad (MZItmsBadPackage)

Comment: I have the same exact problem and get the same exact errors and codes. My Apple-Hosted IAP package validates fine on the new iMac 27, the when I distribute I get the errors. I tried the same package from my MacBook Pro and it Validated and Distributed fine. No solutions or ideas yet. Anyone?

Comment: What Xcode version and OS is your MBP running?

Comment: MBP running OSX 10.8.3 Xcode 4.6.1 -- iMac OSX 10.8.3 Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: Okay, now I get the same errors on both machines. I tried several different IAP packages even those I did not update and get the same errors. It must be an Apple Server thing. Error Code 4029 is when server is attempting to shut down. I also found people with the same issue in the past who said it worked 5, 10, or 20 minutes later.

Comment: Yes it seems to be a server problem. I was able to upload with Application Loader instead. To do so you must choose in Xcode to export as .pkg Package. Then use the "Application Loader" app. It is much better.